# How to stop iframes blocking my JS?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, pageload

I've got a page which uses both the [unofficial github buttons](http://markdotto.github.com/github-buttons/), and code which I highlight using this [syntax highlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

The problem is, the two github buttons are iframes which both make requests to `api.github.com`, and it can sometimes take a while for them to load.

While the buttons are loading (and chrome says "waiting for api.github.com"), the syntax highlighter's javascript can't execute. It doesn't execute until the iframes are fully loaded, which sometimes can take quite a while.

I'd much prefer to have no github buttons and have my code highlighted faster than have the github buttons load first. How can I achieve this?

I've tried loading the buttons asynchronously with javascript, but they don't load properly because the javascript in the iframes doesn't execute for some reason.

Here's how I load up the SyntaxHighlighter (in the `<head>`)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/shCore.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/brushes.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['gutter'] = false;
SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['toolbar'] = false;
SyntaxHighlighter.all();
</script>
```

And the iframe HTML looks like this:

```
<iframe src="http://markdotto.github.com/github-buttons/github-btn.html?user=user&amp;repo=repo&amp;type=watch&amp;count=true&amp;size=large" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="165px" height="30px"></iframe>
<iframe src="http://markdotto.github.com/github-buttons/github-btn.html?user=user&amp;repo=repo&amp;type=fork&amp;count=true&amp;size=large" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="165px" height="30px"></iframe>
```

How can I stop the buttons from blocking my JS?

Comment: I think in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7SUFLFu3HI they talk about solution how to create 3rth party plugin that don't block the site, and they use javascript and iframes.

Comment: Do the scripts appear before the iframe in your markup?

Comment: @Eric yes, the scripts are in the head, whereas the iframes are in the  body of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with jquery deferred. You can find an example at http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You could assign the iframe src after the document has loaded using javascript.
That way your page would load just find, and then these could take all the time they want.

Some like:

```
<script>
function showbuttons()
{
  var path1 = "http://markdotto.github.com/github-buttons/github-btn.html?user=user&amp;repo=repo&amp;type=watch&amp;count=true&amp;size=large";
  var path2 = "http://markdotto.github.com/github-buttons/github-btn.html?user=user&amp;repo=repo&amp;type=fork&amp;count=true&amp;size=large";
  document.getElementById('frame1').src = path1;
    document.getElementById('frame2').src = path2;
}
</script>
```

html:

```
<body onload="showbuttons()">
<iframe id="frame1" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="165px" height="30px"></iframe>
<iframe id="frame2" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" width="165px" height="30px"></iframe>
```

Comment: I've tried that, but if you do that the iframes don't load properly, as the javascript for the buttons doesn't execute.

Comment: I wonder why, iframes load independent documents and call the same functions as the main document when they complete loading.

Comment: I think it's because the code in the iframe is making it's own HTTP request.

Comment: There are no restrictions to prevent that either. Has to be something else. A js-fiddle may help take a look at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

to block an iframe from appearing on other people's websites, you can use this script

```
if(document.querySelector('html').ownerDocument.location.ancestorOrigins[0]==undefined==false){
    document.querySelector('html').innerHTML='hello plagiat web.....visit official web... visit here : '+document.querySelector('html').ownerDocument.URL;}
```